# Python syntax error while taking an IP address as an input

Tags: python

I have a text file called sample_ips.txt containing some random IP addresses as follows:-

```
182.0.0.15
182.0.0.16
182.0.0.17
```

I am giving an IP address as an input to check if that IP exist in the text file it prints true else false.

Here is my code snippet:-

```
ip_input = str(input("Enter IP:"))
ip = open("sample_ips", "r")
data = ip.readlines()
for ips in data:
    ips = ips.strip("\n")
    if ip_input in ips:
        print "true"
    else:
        print "false"
```

It's throwing a syntax error

```
File "<string>", line 1
182.0.0.15
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid sytanx
```

I think it is not able to take the input as a string despite me declaring it as a string in my code. Any help? 
Thanks

Comment: Use `raw_input` not `input`.

Comment: I did, it didnt work @AshwiniChaudhary

Comment: FYI, you should not be using input() here - as per https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=input#input, the input function will execute what ever the user writes as python code, which is not what you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, this works:

```
input = raw_input("Enter IP:")
ip = open("sample_ips.txt", "r")
data = ip.readlines()
for ips in data:
    ips = ips.strip("\n")
    if input in ips:
        print "true"
    else:
        print "false"
```

[image: Working for me]

:edit:

Python3 version

```
input = input("Enter IP:")
ip = open("sample_ips.txt", "r")
data = ip.readlines()
for ips in data:
    ips = ips.strip("\n")
    if input in ips:
        print ("true")
    else:
        print ("false")
```

Comment: It gives TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found

Comment: Which Python are you using, 2 or 3? This works quite well with Python 2.

Comment: I am using Python 3 at the moment. It's working the same in python 2

Comment: This solution is working for me, for on both python 2 and python 3.

Comment: Okay sorry I take it back, it worked in Python version 2 but In tried using just 'input' in version 3,still didnt work. But thanks anyways

Comment: You need to use raw_input, as input tries to evaluate the input as python code.

Answer (score 0):

```
input_ip = raw_input("Enter IP:") # In python 2.x. If you use input() then type your inputs as string (>>Enter IP:"182.0.0.15")
#input_ip = input("Enter IP:")  for python 3.x

with open("ip.txt", "r") as ip:
    data = ip.readlines()
    for ips in data:
        ips = ips.strip("\n")
        if input_ip in ips:
            print ("true")
        else:
            print ("false")
```